# Does python3 asyncio use a work stealing scheduler like Rust Tokio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Does Python 3 asyncio use a work-stealing scheduler like Rust Tokio? What's the behavior of the default scheduler? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["Work-stealing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing) is a property of multi-threaded executors. Python asyncio's executor (event loop) is single-threaded, so it's by definition not work-stealing. The behavior of the asyncio event loop wrt threads is documented (among other places) in the [Concurrency and Multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading) section of the documentation.

As for the algorithm used for scheduling, it's intentionally unspecified, but the [stdlib implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee464322eb5ede56db6b501279f700638c5c9103/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1837) uses:

- a deque to store callbacks that are ready to run (those scheduled with `call_soon()` or `create_task()`) as well as those associated with file descriptors that are ready to read/write, and
- a binary heap to store callbacks scheduled for a particular time ordered by the absolute time when they're supposed to fire. This covers callbacks scheduled by `loop.call_after()` and `loop.call_at()`, but also continuation of coroutines suspended by `asyncio.sleep()`, which internally uses `loop.call_at()`.

At each loop iteration the loop [waits for something to happen](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee464322eb5ede56db6b501279f700638c5c9103/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1818) on file descriptors associated with coroutines and [sets the timeout](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee464322eb5ede56db6b501279f700638c5c9103/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1816) to interrupt the sleep at the nearest time-based callback, in case nothing interesting happens before that. It proceeds to call the ready callbacks and the timeouts scheduled to run at the current or earlier time. This is repeated until the event loop is instructed to stop.

Comment: I see. So application needs to decide which executor to spawn the task into if multiple executors are created in a multi-core system?

Comment: @user855 I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking. In Python there is rarely a reason to run multiple event loops - a single event loop is designed to scale to an abitrary number of coroutines, as many as system resources like memory permit. And even if one did spawn multiple event loops, each in its own thread, they still wouldn't use multiple cores because [the GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) would effectively serialize them. Because of the GIL **all** Python code runs on a single core at any given time.

Comment: I see. Thank you! That answers my question